# Javascript array reconstruct with merging/filtering

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have two javascript arrays one

```
var sectors = [
   { name: 'Fishing' }, {name: 'Bowling'}...
];
```

other one

```
var organizations = [
    {name: 'Carson ind', tel: '1545454', fax: 1215454, sectors: ['Banking', 'Fishing']},
    {name: 'Superman & Co.', tel: '1545454', fax: 1215454, sectors: ['Financing', 'Banking']}, 
     ....
    ];
```

How can i create new array with this two array with below structure.

```
var newArray = [
   {sector : 'Banking', organizations : 
    [
      {name: 'Superman & Co.', tel: '1545454', fax: 1215454, sectors: ['Financing', 'Banking']}, 
      ....
    ]
   }
 ];
```

Right now Im using underscore and my code

```
    var newArray = [];
    _.each(vm.allSectors, function(sec){
        newArray[sec.name] = _.filter(vm.allOrganizations, function(org) {
           return _.filter(org.sector, function(sector){
              return sector === sec.name;
           });
        });

    });
```

It doesn't giving me the result i want its just return lots of sector array only.

Comment: Can you please explain how you want tk merge them?

Comment: I want a new array with a key as 'sector.name' and value as object from organizations array that should have contain same 'sector.name' from sectors array.

Comment: please add an example of the wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically user6188402 answer, but with fixed lambdas

```
result = sectors.map(s => {
    return {
        sector: s.name,
        organizations: organizations.filter(o => o.sectors.indexOf(s.name) > -1)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This proposal uses an object for the wanted sectors and iterates `organisations` and creates a new object and insert the actual data to the organisation property.

```js
var sectors = [{ name: 'Fishing' }, { name: 'Bowling' }],
    sectorHash = {},
    organizations = [{ name: 'Carson ind', tel: '1545454', fax: 1215454, sectors: ['Banking', 'Fishing'] }, { name: 'Superman & Co.', tel: '1545454', fax: 1215454, sectors: ['Financing', 'Banking'] }],
    newArray = [];

sectors.forEach(function (a) {
    sectorHash[a.name] = true;
});

organizations.forEach(function (a) {
    a.sectors.forEach(function (b) {
        if (sectorHash[b]) {
            if (!this[b]) {
                this[b] = { sector: b, organzations: [] };
                newArray.push(this[b]);
            }
            this[b].organzations.push(a);
        }
    }, this);
}, Object.create(null));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newArray, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```